# converting from type double to currency using data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am creating c3 charts and want to change the format of the data. Is there a way of converting double to spend format

```
public ActionResult FlugBarSpend()
        {
            DataModel db = new DataModel();
            var test = db.Database.SqlQuery<FlugBarSpendData>("exec sp_FlugBarSpend").ToList();
            return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        public class FlugBarSpendData
        {
            public int Month { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public double Spend { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: *the data annotation below only works if spend was type decimal* -- How do you get to this conclusion?

Comment: Should be closed as not-reproducible because the initial assumption isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

It works for `double`. How are you displaying/rendering it? Trivial sample below

Model

---

```cs
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public double Price {get; set;}

}
```

Controller

---

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SampleViewModel(){Name = "Item 1", Price = 2.99});
    }
}
```

View

---

```html
<div>       
    <!-- In an text input field -->
    <p>@Model.Name : @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)</p>

    <!-- As text -->
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price)</p>
</div>
```

Hth

---

Update:

As the name of the attribute implies, **[DisplayFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=netframework-4.8)**, it *Specifies how data fields are **displayed and formatted*** (emphasis mine)

You're returning *data* (JSON), it will be up to the client to *display and format* it appropriately. Data returned isn't changed - a currency symbol makes that value a `string`.

If that's your intent, returning a `string` version of a numeric value, then adjust your `model` to return a `string`. You can format it however you deem fit (manually). IMHO, that wouldn't be advisable (though I have no idea what your intent is, so again, that's just my opinion).

Comment: Hi, my class is in the controller. I will edit my code to show

Comment: @sun22 As the name of the attribute implies, **[DisplayFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=netframework-4.8)**, it _Specifies how data fields are **displayed and formatted**_ (emphasis mine). You're returning _data_ (JSON), it will be up to the client to _display and format_ it appropriately (not changing it's type - a currency symbol makes value a `string`).

Comment: Thanks! What about if I just wanted to display it as a currency format without a currency symbol?

Comment: @sun22 Unsure what you mean by _"currency format without a currency symbol"_ - you probably mean [number formatting based on some culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting-in-dotnet-framework) - e.g. `100.00` vs `100,00`